# How can I evaluate part of an Expression that references a parameter?

Tags: c#, expression

I am writing a method intended to parse a method call expression and determine (1) the method being called and (2) the arguments being passed. I can retrieve the method just fine but am having trouble evaluating the argument expressions.

Here is the code:

```
public static void InspectExpression(Expression<Action<Input>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    var methodName = memberExpression.Method.Name;
    Console.WriteLine("The expression calls the {0} method.", methodName);

    var argumentExpression = memberExpression.Arguments[0];
    var argumentLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(argumentExpression);
    var compiled = argumentLambda.Compile();
    var argumentValue = compiled();

    Console.WriteLine("The expression would pass {0} as the first argument to {1}", argumentValue, methodName);
}
```

I am calling it with the following code:

```
public class Input
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public static void MethodName(string arg)
{
    //Doesn't matter what this does
}

public static void Main()
{
    InspectExpression( i => MethodName(i.SomeProperty) );
}
```

However this yields the following exception:

```
[System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'i' of type 'Input' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined]
```

This makes sense since there is no way to evaluate that expression without knowing the value of the input, since the argument is computed based on the expression's input.

So I tried adding the input like this:

```
public static void InspectExpression(Expression<Action<Input>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    var methodName = memberExpression.Method.Name;
    Console.WriteLine("The expression calls the {0} method.", methodName);

    var argumentExpression = memberExpression.Arguments[0];
    var argumentLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Input,string>>(argumentExpression);
    var compiled = argumentLambda.Compile();

    var sampleInput = new Input { SomeProperty = "Hello world" };
    var argumentValue = compiled(sampleInput);

    Console.WriteLine("The expression would pass {0} as the first argument to {1}", argumentValue, methodName);
}
```

This raised the exception:

```
[System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration]
```

I'm guessing I have to add a parameter reference to the expression somehow, but I'm at a loss exactly how to do this.

Give a sample input, how can I retrieve the computed argument to this expression?

Here is a [link to a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jHbVMx) in case you'd like to try it out or use it as the basis of an example solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass a set of parameters to the `Expression.Lambda<...>()` call - you should be able to use the same set of parameters as the original `expression`, so change your definition of `argumentLambda` to:

```
var argumentLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Input,string>>(argumentExpression, expression.Parameters);
```

Comment: Holy cats, it works. I knew it'd be something simple! Thank you!